# CGLib and serialization

Tags: java, spring, serialization, command-pattern, cglib

What I want to do is to serialize a class that
implements a command pattern so that I can run it later. In best
of all worlds, I would like to serialize an anonymous class (I'm
aware of the problems with this)

What makes it a bit complicated is that I'm in a spring environement and
the anonymous class that I wish to serialize is defined in a class that will
be proxied by CGLib.

My initial try:

```
public interface CallLater implements Serializeable {
     public run();
}


@Service
public class TestService implements Serializeable {

     public doSomethingMore() { /* Code */ }

     public void doSomething() {

         CallLater job = new CallLater() {
            private static final long serialVersionUID = 4415017504667122645L;

            @Override
            public void run() {
               doSomethingMore();

            }
         }

         storeJob(job);
    }
}
```

E.g The storeJob will serialize the object and store it for later and it's
this part that fails. I have not included the code for this but is's just 
a ObjectOutputStream call

I'm aware that the entire TestService class needs to be serialize. The problem is
that it's wrapped threw a CGLib proxy and this proxy does not implement serializeable
(My guess is that this one can't be serialized).

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: A stack trace would be helpful

Comment: The CGLib proxy is a subclass of TestService, and thus implements Serializable, doesn't it? Maybe it prevents serialization by implementing the writeObject method?

Comment: @Christian: My guess is that `TestService` has a reference to something non-serializable somewhere.

Answer (score 0):

You should only serialize the "target". So you have a reference to the proxy right? There will be away to get the target of that proxy so that you can serialize that.

The thing to do would be to break point the app just before the serialization and dig around in that context for the property you need. Or there might be some proxy utils or something.

Comment: Does a CGLib proxy change behaviour of methods in such a way that an invocation from within the proxied instance trigger the proxied method? If it does, the deserialized TestService target in your solution, Michael, would no longer be proxied, and therefore it would lack any behaviour that the proxy adds to the doSomethingMore() method.

Comment: No - spring's default aop does not allow invocation of the proxy version from within the instance. Spring's aop works at method level and does not change the actual class.

Comment: You should however, investigate why the proxy is there, what is the purpose? If it is important it might be tricky to reload the spring bean and proxy it as well. Maybe you should abstract the proxy layer away from the object you're serializing